# Storage and query efficiency in MySQL and mariadb database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning, data-warehouse

I am new to querying in very big databases. I would like to know if partitioning a very large data table in several improves or decreases efficiency in storage and the speed of queries. For example if a I have a very big data table with information worth a year with 300 million rows and nearly 30 columns, is it better to break it into 12 months or keep it asis? will it improve effiency or storage, or none?

Comment: Diegolog -- to avoid having this closed as "too broad", describe the application and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Rick thanks for the suggestion. I will try to add some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  No.  Disk space will be slightly *larger*; performance is not likely to improve.

Long answer:

Each partition is essentially a separate table; each table has some pre-allocated space.  A partition has 4-7MB of "free" space each.

Partitioning does not inherently bring any performance boost.  (In some cases, it give a slight slowdown.)

That said, there are 4 [*use cases*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) that I know of where partitioning, if carefully done, can provide a noticeable speed up.  You have said nothing to indicate yours is one of those cases.  The most common is a "time series", wherein you need to delete "old" data.  The benefit comes from `DROP PARTITION` being virtually instantaneous, as opposed to `DELETE`.

Please describe your data situation -- the data type, the schema, and the important queries.  If it is a Data Warehouse application, then "time series" may be of use.  More likely is [*Summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables); they can often be used to greatly speed up "Reports", as opposed to lengthy `GROUP BYs`.

Comment: Rick. Thank you very much for your answer. The database is a shipments over time data. meaning I have a lot of data on shipments scans showing where they were recieved and where the were sent. this is the biggest data table. There is some shimpment related information that is smaller in size in another data table somewhere around the 100 million rows. On top of that I have some information related to each one of the items related in relatively tiny data tables that dont go over the million rows. I am trying to get the number of shipments on different locations and given certain features

Comment: @Diegolog - You're welcome. I'd be glad to help further, but things are still rather vague.